# Randomly subsetting 1 observation per site and date

Tags: r, subset

I have read many posts on the site about randomly subsetting a large dataset for observations based on date -- for the first, last, or a specific date. However, I have a different challenge that requires me to subsample a large dataset by site AND date. I want to keep all sites in the subsetted dataset, but only include 1 date observation per site.

More specifically, I have a large dataset (for community ecology!) of insect community observations (n=2000) across 4 years. They were observed from ~900 sites, but each site has between 1 and 6 date observations within a year, with no sites repeated between years (this is why previous posts looking to subset a specific date range cannot apply here). Subsetting in this particular way is critical because of type of statistical analysis I am using - including spatial autocorrelation terms in the analysis means that I can only include one observation per site.

So the full dataset looks something like:

```
Site        Date        Ladybug
Baumgarten  6/24/2014   2
Baumgarten  8/6/2014    0
Baumgarten  8/20/2014   3
Baumgarten  7/8/2014    0
Baumgarten  7/22/2014   1
Berkevich   7/9/2014    0
Berkevich   7/23/2014   4
Berkevich   8/8/2014    0
Berkevich   8/22/2014   0
Boehm       6/24/2014   2

# dput(data)
dd <- structure(list(Site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Baumgarten", "Berkevich", "Boehm"), class = "factor"),  Date = structure(c(1L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 1L), .Label = c("6/24/2014", "7/22/2014", "7/23/2014", "7/8/2014",  "7/9/2014", "8/20/2014", "8/22/2014", "8/6/2014", "8/8/2014" ), class = "factor"), Ladybug = c(2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L,  4L, 0L, 0L, 2L)), .Names = c("Site", "Date", "Ladybug"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -10L))
```

And my desired subsetted dataset would look something like:

```
Site        Date        Ladybugs
Baumgarten  8/20/2014   3
Berkevich   7/9/2014    0
Boehm       6/24/2014   2
```

I have dates entered in both MM/DD/YYYY and DOY format (since sites don't repeat between years, DOY x site subsetting will still work to ensure no repeating sites), so code that uses either could work.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `dd[tapply(seq.int(nrow(dd)), dd$Site, function(x) x[sample.int(length(x), 1)]), ]`

Comment: because of the way `sample` works, this could simplify if you always have at least two per site to `dd[tapply(seq.int(nrow(dd)), dd$Site, sample, size = 1), ]`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data is a `data.frame` named `df`, you could use `dplyr` and do the following:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Site) %>%
  sample_n(1)

# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# Groups: Site [3]
#  
#         Site      Date Ladybug
#       (fctr)    (fctr)   (int)
# 1 Baumgarten 8/20/2014       3
# 2  Berkevich 8/22/2014       0
# 3      Boehm 6/24/2014       2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` you can use:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(DT)
DT[,.SD[sample(.N,1)], by=Site]
```

This gives you

```
         Site      Date Ladybug
1: Baumgarten 8/20/2014       3
2:  Berkevich 7/23/2014       4
3:      Boehm 6/24/2014       2
```

Comment: Nice one. I came up with the same code at the same time :P

Answer (score 1):

You could also use base-R for this. It splits the data by site, samples one row and returns that. Then results get bound together.

```
set.seed(123)

res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(dat,dat$Site),function(x){x[sample(nrow(x),1),]}))
```

Another possibility is data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
set.seed(123)
res <- dat[,.SD[sample(.N,1)],Site]
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibly inefficient method, but it gets the job done.

```
levels <- length(unique(data$Site))
rowselect<- sapply(1:levels, function(x) {
  elem <- which(array==unique(array)[x])
  if(length(elem)<2){
    return(elem)
  } else {
    return(sample(elem,1))
  }
})
```

this gives the rowindex for 1 randomly selected row for each site.

Comment: thank you all - I will start with base R and report back.

Comment: This errors on my machine, and will probably be inefficient with larger datasets/multiple groups.

Comment: instead of the if/else, you can use `x[sample.int(length(x), 1)]` which will always return a vector of length 1 even if x is length 1